# Please explain this conditional expectation equality

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I understand that E[X|Y] is a random variable. But I am kind of confused about the following :

$$
\int_{\{Y=y_i\}} E[X|Y] dP = E[X|Y=y_i]P(Y=y_i)
$$

In the above, P is a probability measure , then when you integrate the E[X|Y] over the regioan of {Y=yi} , I can write $\int E[X|Y]*I_{(Y=yi)}dP$ , but I still don't see the above. Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the conditional expectation ${\rm E}[X\mid Y]$ has the property that
$$
\int_A {\rm E}[X\mid Y]\,\mathrm dP=\int_A X\,\mathrm dP,\quad A\in\sigma(Y).
$$
Since $\{Y=y\}\in \sigma(Y)$ for all $y$, we have
$$
\int_{\{Y=y\}}{\rm E}[X\mid Y]\,\mathrm dP=\int_{\{Y=y\}}X\,\mathrm dP=\int_\Omega X\mathbf{1}_{\{Y=y\}}\,\mathrm dP.
$$
At last, recall that if $A\subseteq \Omega$ with $P(A)>0$, then the conditional expectation given $A$ is given by
$$
{\rm E}[X\mid A]=\frac{1}{P(A)}\int_{\Omega}X\mathbf{1}_A\,\mathrm dP.
$$
Use this with $A=\{Y=y\}$ to conclude.

Comment: Thanks for the proof, however what is your approach if you don't know your first property $\int_A {\rm E}[X\mid Y]\,\mathrm dP=\int_A X\,\mathrm dP,\quad A\in\sigma(Y)$ , since I saw some proof using my question to prove your first property.

Comment: The first property is part of the definition of the conditional expectation given a sigma-algebra. If that's not how it's defined to you, please tell me how it's defined.

Comment: I read from this note , page 5 http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/kross1/Lec8_1008.pdf

Comment: It follows from the "orthogonality" with $V=\mathbf{1}_A$ (page 1).

Comment: Oh, ok, it's just a different way of expression. Thanks a lot for your help.